# Браузер откатывает перестановку DOM элементов силами JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, webbrowser

Коллеги, вопрос, который никак не могу решить.

Все ссылки на материалы в конце.

Хотел реализовать слайдер с цикличной перестановкой. Есть три слайда минимум. Все три на странице, но виден только один - средний. Анимация проходит за счет CSS transition на ширину.

То есть для переключения в правый слайд я убираю ширину левого, удаляю левый и вставляю справа следующий слайд. Так как слайдов три и всё зациклено, я подставляю справа тот слайд, который только что удалил.
Для переключения в левый слайд я убираю слайд справа, убираю его ширину в 0, ставлю этот же слайд слева (т.к. всё зациклено), потом раздвигаю ширину в стандартную.

Ключевой момент - это прерывание блока выполнения кода браузером ([вот тут на хабре про это написано](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224187/)). То есть, если подряд идет снижение ширины в 0, потом подстановка сладйда и сразу расширение в стандарт, то анимации не будет, т.к. браузер "проглотит" сужение и расширение ввиду того, что посчитает, что мы вернулись в ту же точку, откуда начали. Он просто вставит слайд и анимации мы не увидим. Для этого нужно прервать выполнение кода обращением к какому-нибудь свойству. Тогда браузер очнется и сделает всё после подстановки и мы увидим транзишн. Один из подобных блоков находится в скрипте "слайдер" на строчках 160 - 166.

**Теперь к делу.** Если нажимать просто "вперед", то всё отлично работает. Если нажимать "назад", то всё отлично работает. Если пару раз нажать "назад" и следом "вперед" без перезагрузки - тоже работает. Но вот если нажать сначала "Вперед", а потом "назад", то браузер начинает вести себя неадекватно. В древе html видно, что до анимации он убирает слайд в конце и ставит его в начало, затем расширяет его по ширине и видна анимация. Но как только закончится анимация, браузер как будто откатывает изменения назад: удаляет слайд из начала и ставит обратно в конец. В коде этого нет! Это какая - то фишка оптимизации операций на странице или типа того.

Почему я абсолютно уверен, что это мулька браузера, а не ошибка алгоритма? Вот почему: если закомментировать обращение к свойству offsetHeight на строке 165, то всё начинает работать правильно с точки зрения алгоритма и расстановки слайдов, НО пропадает анимация, т.к. нет обращения к свойству в ключевой момент, чтобы прервать поток выполнения кода.

[Ссылка на gitHub](https://github.com/SukhininAlexey/JS-Homework/tree/master/Slider)

[Через файлообменник dropmefiles](http://dropmefiles.com/Hrb4z)

[Через Гуглодиск](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hJZuHp2Ex8bRSRn4E9lCGcE3-UvJ4xMo?usp=sharing)

[JSbin для быстроты](https://jsbin.com/tojawam/edit?html,css,js,output)

**Очень прошу не бить по рукам.** Да, ООП - структура прикручена криво и зря. Да, возможно, слайдер можно сделать проще. Но вопрос не в слайдере а в понимании того, почему это происходит. Я перевариваю любые ссылки на инфо-ресурсы и статьи на русском и английском языке. Разобраться очень хочется

**Весь код слайдера ниже.** Перед проблемной строкой внизу стоит комментарий

```
     window.onload = function (){
    var mySlider = new Slider('slider-1', 500, 300, '1s linear');
    mySlider.render();
    console.log(mySlider.getSliderObj());
    var FWD = document.getElementById('fwd');
    FWD.addEventListener('click',function(){
         mySlider.nextSlide.call(mySlider);
    });
    var BWD = document.getElementById('bwd');
    BWD.addEventListener('click',function(){
        mySlider.prevSlide.call(mySlider);
    });

}

function Slider(newSliderId, newSliderWidth, newSliderHeight, widthTransitionCSS){

    // Поля класса
    var currentPosition = 1;
    var sliderObj = document.getElementById(newSliderId);
    var slidesArray = [];
    var sliderWidth = newSliderWidth;
    var sliderHeight = newSliderHeight;
    var transition ='width ' + widthTransitionCSS;
    this.sliderObjy = sliderObj;
    this.slidesArrayy = slidesArray;

    // Геттеры
    this.getSliderObj = function(){
        return sliderObj;
    }
    this.getSlidesArray = function(){
        return slidesArray;
    }
    this.getSliderHeight = function(){
        return sliderHeight;
    }    
    this.getSliderWidth = function(){
        return sliderWidth;
    }
    this.getTransition = function(){
        return transition;
    }
    this.getCurrentPosition = function(){
        return currentPosition;
    }

    // Смысловые методы
    this.stepFwrd = function(){
        if(currentPosition + 1 >= slidesArray.length){
            return currentPosition = 0;
        }else{
            return ++currentPosition;
        }
    }
    this.stepBwrd = function(){
        if(currentPosition - 1 < 0){
            return currentPosition = slidesArray.length - 1;
        }else{
            return --currentPosition;
        }
    }
}

Slider.prototype.render = function(){
    var sliderObj = this.getSliderObj();
    sliderObj.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(sliderObj);
    var arrayOfSlides = this.getSlidesArray();

    while(sliderObj.hasChildNodes()){
        if(sliderObj.firstChild.tagName === 'DIV'){
            arrayOfSlides.push(sliderObj.firstChild);
        }
        sliderObj.removeChild(sliderObj.firstChild);
    }
    console.log(arrayOfSlides);

    var slidesWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    slidesWrapper.style.width = (this.getSliderWidth() * 3) + 'px';
    slidesWrapper.style.height = (this.getSliderHeight()) + 'px';
    slidesWrapper.style.margin = '0px -' + this.getSliderWidth() + 'px';
    slidesWrapper.style.display = 'flex';

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        slidesWrapper.appendChild(arrayOfSlides[i]);
    }

    sliderObj.appendChild(slidesWrapper);

    sliderObj.style.display = 'block';
}



Slider.prototype.nextSlide = function(){
    var slidesWrapper = this.getSliderObj().firstChild;
    var arrayOfSlides = this.getSlidesArray();

    var currentPosition = this.getCurrentPosition();
    var previousPosition = (function(){
        if(currentPosition - 1 < 0){
            return arrayOfSlides.length - 1;
        }else{
            return currentPosition - 1;
        }
    })();

    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].style.transition = this.getTransition();
    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].offsetHeight;
    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].style.width = '0px';

    // Становимся в новую позицию
    currentPosition = this.stepFwrd();

    // Не следующая по счету позиция, а следующая загружаемая позиция
    var nextPosition = (function(){
        if(currentPosition + 1 >= arrayOfSlides.length){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return currentPosition + 1;
        }
    })();

console.log(this.getCurrentPosition());
    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
        slidesWrapper.removeChild(arrayOfSlides[previousPosition]);
        arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].removeAttribute('style');
        slidesWrapper.appendChild(arrayOfSlides[nextPosition]);
    }); 
}

Slider.prototype.prevSlide = function(){
    var slidesWrapper = this.getSliderObj().firstChild;
    var arrayOfSlides = this.getSlidesArray();

    var currentPosition = this.getCurrentPosition();;
    var nextPosition = (function(){
        if(currentPosition + 1 >= arrayOfSlides.length){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return currentPosition + 1;
        }
    })();

    slidesWrapper.removeChild(arrayOfSlides[nextPosition]);

    var currentPosition = this.stepBwrd();

    var previousPosition = (function(){
        if(currentPosition - 1 < 0){
            return arrayOfSlides.length - 1;
        }else{
            return currentPosition - 1;
        }
    })();

    console.log(this.getSliderWidth());

    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].style.width = '0px';
    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].style.transition = this.getTransition();
    slidesWrapper.insertBefore(arrayOfSlides[previousPosition],slidesWrapper.firstChild);

    // Если поставить комментарий ниже, то алгоритм заработает. Но пропадет анимация при движении слайдов влево
    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].offsetHeight;
    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].style.width = this.getSliderWidth() + 'px';


    arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
        arrayOfSlides[previousPosition].removeAttribute('style');
    });
}
```

Comment: Если «это мулька браузера», то значит это не работает в каком-то одном конкретном браузере и работает во всех остальных? Если не работает везде, значит это «мулька» всё-таки алгоритма :) (код ещё не запускал, вы удобный запускабельный пример не дали, а мне лень)

Comment: Добавил ссылку на JSbin (https://jsbin.com/tojawam/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: При закомментированном offsetHeight код работает, потому что у вас transitionend не срабатывает (потому что никакой transition и не начинался)

Comment: Вы вешаете одноразовые transitionend на элементы, а после использования не убираете их. Похоже, это неправильно; я досканально в коде ещё не разбирался, но, возможно, причина глюков именно в этом

Comment: При замене `transitionend` на `setTimeout(..., 1000)` (который одноразовый) глюк пропадает, так что похоже я угадал. Значит это «мулька» всё-таки алгоритма :)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду событие transitioned в конце функции prevSlide? Можно вообще удалить блок, посвященный этому событию, но глюк всё равно останется.

Comment: Я имею в виду оба transitionend, замените их оба на setTimeout — глюк исчезнет

Comment: Действительно помогает... Я вот только не понимаю, почему? Можно чуть-чуть подробнее? И еще момент: разве установка таймеров не является примером плохого тона в асинхронном js? Вроде как мы должны ориентироваться именно на события, а не на magic numbers.

Comment: Потому что вы не убираете transitionend из слайда после его срабатывания. Когда запускается prevSlide, после завершения анимации срабатывает transitionend, который был добавлен внутри nextSlide, потому что вы его не удалили после использования — допишите в них какой-нибудь console.log и сами всё увидите.

Comment: Последний вопрос. Всё решается удалением transitioned слушателя после завершения транзишна. Но у меня в данный слушатель записана анонимная функция. И мне её лень перебивать в именованную. Нашел любопытное заклинание с использованием arguments.callee. Но вот некоторые люди считают, что это использовать нельзя. Насколько плохо будет использовать такой подход? Или не париться и оставить, как есть?